# C# performance, speed up string array in class

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I am in need of more performance and this is what I currently have.

```
public static class ValidateConditions
{

     public static bool CheckWildCards(string hcdpPlnCvgCD, string HcdpPmtFctrCd, string hccCpmtFctrCd, IBizClaimWorkflowContext workspaceContext, string conditionType)
     {
         var patterns = new string[3];
         
         if(condition)
         {
            patterns = new string[]{
                 hcdpPlnCvgCD,
                "DEF",
                "HIJ"
            };
         }
         else
         {
            patterns = new string[]{
                 hcdpPlnCvgCD,
                "yyy",
                "zzz"
            };
         }
         
          var matchResult = dataMart.SponsorPackage.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.ExternalPolicy, pattern)).FirstOrDefault();

     }

}
```

I am hearing that this can be a performance issue as "These arrays should be declared as private static as we only create each array once when the class is initialized instead of a new array every time the call to method is made.  Since it is be called a million times a day.

So I'm a bit confused on how to achieve this.

I was looking at doing this in the class  `private static string[] patterns { get; set; }`  but I still end up having to do `new string[]{...}   so how can I really do this properly?

Update:  fixing code.

Comment: What is the meaning of `(s.ExternalPolicy, pattern)` obviously this is a compiler error. If this is going to another method, and you are doing a lookup on the patterns. i would consider making them a `HashSet`.

Comment: You know that `Where` needs to produce a `bool`? What's `.Where(s => (s.ExternalPolicy, pattern))` doing?

Comment: `public static bool CheckWildCards(data, condition)` <-- this is not valid C#

Comment: That is what happens when I mess up with trying to quickly simplify     public static bool CheckWildCards(string hcdpPlnCvgCD, string HcdpPmtFctrCd, string hccCpmtFctrCd, IBizClaimWorkflowContext workspaceContext, string conditionType)

Comment: @JeremyMiller - We are always keen to get a [mcve].

Comment: @JeremyMiller - Please fix your code and answer the above comments.

Comment: @Enigmativity   Ok, fixed.

Comment: @JeremyMiller - No, your code isn't fixed.

Comment: @JeremyMiller - No, you haven't answered the questions in the comments.

Comment: @Enigmativity   I passed in hcdpPlnCvgCD   ,  If it is too hard for you , then I will create a new question for someone else to answer.  cheers

Comment: @JeremyMiller - What's `.Where(s => (s.ExternalPolicy, pattern))`? It's not valid code.

Comment: Is my question asking for you to figure out my linq statement.   I'm not wasting my time fixing a big linq statement.   You can ignore that as I'm not fixing it.    .Where(blah.....

Comment: They can't be static if the contents vary based on invocation. I mean, you could _cache_ them perhaps - but they certainly couldn't be `static`.

Comment: `so how can I really do this properly?` You could have the static part of the arrays `static` and then `Concat` the extra entries as needed. I doubt it will give you a great deal of benefits (these are _tiny_ arrays) but profile it to check.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the variables only once.

```
public static class ValidateConditions
{
    private static string[] Patterns1 = new string[]{
        "ABC",
        "DEF",
        "HIJ"
    };
    private static string[] Patterns2 = new string[]{
        "xxx",
        "yyy",
        "zzz"
    };

    public static bool CheckWildCards(MyClass data, bool condition)
    {
        var patterns = condition ? Patterns1 : Patterns2; 
         
        var matchResult = data.SponsorPackage.Where(s => MyMethod(s.ExternalPolicy, pattern)).FirstOrDefault();
        //etc....
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually had variables inside  so instead of "ABC" is it  hcdpPlan  and with this is saying it doesn't exist in the current context   ( its passed in to the method CheckWildCards

Comment: @JeremyMiller - So your question doesn't actually reflect what you're really doing?

Comment: @Enigmativity   Ok,  fixed

Comment: @JeremyMiller - So now that you've updated the question this isn't the answer anymore.

Comment: True @Enigmativity    Thoughts on what I need to do ?  Thanks for your patience

Comment: `Thoughts on what I need to do ?` @JeremyMiller Use your current code.

Comment: @mjwills   I can't  our architect told me  "These arrays should be declared as private static as we only create each array once when the class is initialized instead of a new array every time "

Comment: @JeremyMiller Then chat with them. Their requirement, without more context, is nonsensical. Asking us how to do something when you could sit and pair with the architect seems an odd choice on your part.

Comment: @JeremyMiller - It seems to me that a hybrid approach would work. You haven't given us a [mcve] so I'm not keen to try to suggest a solution.